# Derivative of differential of time-dependent flow of a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, symplectic-geometry, morse-theory

I am reading the book "Morse Theory and Floer Homology" by Audin and Damian. And I am kind of stuck in understanding the last part of a proof in such book. Currently we are trying to prove

> **Proposition 5.4.5.** If a critical point of $H$ is nondegenerate as a periodic solution of the Hamiltonian system, then it is nondegenerate as a critical point of the function $H$.
> [(Screenshot here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5KYT.png)

So, part of the proof is here

> Computed at the critical point $x$ of $H$, the first term is zero and the second one is exactly
> $$
> \left(d^{2} H\right)_{x}\left(X_{f}(x), Z(x)\right)=\left(d^{2} H\right)_{x}(Y, Z)
> $$
> We now suppose that $x$ is nondegenerate as a trajectory of $X_{H}$. This means that for every $Z \neq 0$, we have
> $$
> T_{x} \psi^{1}(Z)-Z \neq 0.
> $$
> [(Screenshot here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLeQy.png)

My main question is in page 138. So it says that $$\frac{d}{dt} T_x \psi^{t}(Z) = T_x \psi^{t} ([X_H, Z])$$

I do not understand where this equality comes from. I have been trying to see if this is a known property of time-dependent flows, but no success until now. Here $X_H$ denotes the time-dependent Hamiltonian vector field.

Here is the things I have tried until now:

1. In the appendix of such book it is known that for time-dependent flows we have that $\frac{dY}{dt} = (dX_t)_{x(t)}Y$ iff $Y(t) = T_{x(t)}\psi^{t}(Y(0))$, where $X_t$ is any time-dependent vector field. So, we can apply this to our case where $X_t = X_H$, but after that I am not sure how to go from $(dX_H)_{x(t)}Y$ to $T_x \psi^{t}([X_H, Z])$.
2. The other thing that I tried to imitate was the fact that for time-dependent vector fields we get a formula for $\frac{d}{dt} \psi^{*} Y_{t}$, where it is very similar with what I want, but at the end this formula is for the pullback of my flow $\psi$ and I want a formula for the push-forward.

Again, maybe this is a basic fact of time-dependent flows and it is easy to prove but if I could get any kind of hint or reference I could look to understand this I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If $(q_i, p_i)$ are local Darboux coordinates at $x$, then (up to sign conventions) the Hamiltonian $X_{H_t}$ is given in coordinates by $$X_{H_t} = \sum_i\left( -\frac{\partial H_t}{\partial p_i} \frac{\partial}{\partial q_i} + \frac{\partial H_t}{\partial q_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial p_i} \right).$$ Then substitute this into the formula and compute. Since both sides of the equation you want are $\mathbb R$-linear in $Z$, it should suffice to check it for the cases that $Z$ is a coordinate tangent vector. This results in a long and messy computation, but it should work out.

Comment: In the book, Proposition 5.4.5 seems to be about time-independent $H$ (as indicated by the paragraph just above that proposition). Otherwise, how would the critical points of $H$ correspond to periodic orbits? For time-independent $H$, the formula you are asking about is essentially one of the definitions of the bracket of vector fields: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_bracket_of_vector_fields#Flows_and_limits

Comment: You are completely right. I think this proposition is for independent time $H$. However, the property you mentioned only makes that expression equal to lie bracket $[X_H, Z]$. But, in the book it says it is equal to the derivative evaluated at it. I mean the conclusion is the same and it uses the fact that $[X_H,Z] \neq 0 $. So we can do it with that property. I just wonder why the author used it with the differential.